# Extending Magento API with customer login

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap

I followed a lot of tutorials about how to extend Magento API but I didn't figure it out why I always get "Invalid api path." My goal is to extend Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api in order to add a new method to login a customer in site. I don't know if something like that is possible, but I need at least to be able to add a new method which just returns a message.

1. Can someone provide me a link where I can find a working module
   which extends Magento API?
2. Is it possible what I want to achieve?
   Thank you,

Yeee..I figured out "Invalid api path." error. Instead of calling

```
$result = $client->call($session_id, 'gw_base_order.createandcapture');
```

it has to be

```
$result = $client->call($session_id, 'resource_name.createandcapture');
```

Wrong tuturial: [Extending Magento API](http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/extending-the-magento-api) and others like this.

I still need an answer for the second question.

Comment: Can I ask why you need a new login method? If you configure the API user correctly you can access all customer data. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is about a mobile application. I want to be able to login a customer through the mobile app.

Comment: I haven't looked into the API permissions lately, but I don't recall there being a concept of "my orders". So I am not sure that once you succeed logging the customer in, that it will have a sensibele ACL associated with it. I think this problem needs solving first, because it is easier to change new user registration to add an API user, then creating a new login method.

Comment: I don't think I get what is your suggestion. I am trying to figure out for the moment how to login a customer in the site through extended API.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer for future visitors and accept it to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of logging users in to access their data from a mobile app for example is more a case for OAuth. 
You can read more about OAuth in Magento [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html) and about the configuration [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html).

The API's are more meant to exchange information not tied to a specific user.